# PHP-7 Installation Error : missing file

Tags: php, installation

I am installing php7 previously have php5.5 installed. Now I uninstalled old version and when I install New version I get this error

[image]

Please help to fix/understand this.

Please ask if you need more info.

Comment: have google the error?

Comment: yes I tried this but not worked :  https://blog.spreendigital.de/2015/09/01/how-to-fix-the-api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-error-for-delphi-10-seattle/

Comment: remove the old entry from regedit and restarts the system then try again